# How do I mock this custom React hook with API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am new to React testing and I am trying to write the tests for this custom hook which basically fetches data from an API and returns it.

```
const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [response, setResponseData] = useState();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] =  useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
          if(response.ok === false){
            throw Error('could not fetch the data for that resource');
          } 
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          setResponseData(data);
          setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.message);
        })
      }, [url]);
    return {response, isLoading};
}

export default useFetch;
```

Since I am new to this I have tried many solutions but nothing is working and I am getting confused too. Can you provide me a simple test for this so that I can get an idea as to how it is done?

Comment: `Since I am new to this I have tried many solutions` like what? It might help to write down the logic in this effect that needs to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

here's an example https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/ using `msw` library to mock server call.

If you mock the server instead of the hook, it will be more resilient to changes.

Moreover, I suggest you to use a library like `react-query` or read source code of them and reimplement them if you want to learn to avoid fetching pitfalls